# How to choose notarization rules applied

Tags: macos, notarize

Apple lately postponed the hardened runtime rule. (see https://www.idownloadblog.com/2019/09/03/notarized-rule-ease-macos-catalina/)

For development purposes I want to choose which ruleset is applied (with or without hardened runtime) when uploading my app to notarization service.

How can I do so? Please advice. I have trouble finding info here.

Comment: Or is there not such option and hardened runtime will appear as a warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time I was now able to answer my own question. Harded runtime notarization issues appear as a warning within the JSON result for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

You asked how to specify whether you want a hardened runtime? At least one way, is to use the `codesign` command. Take a look at the `--options=runtime` flag.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_your_app_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues

Comment: I do know that. But enabling `--options runtime` impacts some application, including mine, even with entitlements enabled.